# Как получать весь трафик с сетевого интерфейса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сеть

У меня имеется виртуальный интерфейс, на него приходит некоторый трафик. Как мне при помощи python сниффать/перехватывать/получать весь трафик с него?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#sniffing

```
from scapy.all import sniff, raw

def on_packet(packet):
    packet.show()

sniff(iface="macvtap1", prn=on_packet)
```

Понадобятся права суперпользователя или `setcap cap_net_raw+ep /usr/bin/python`